# Exec error with curl command - IOException with Working Directory null - Android OS related issue

Tags: android, curl, exec

I have a program that does an exec() of a "netstat" command and a "curl" command. The program runs fine on android 6.0.1. Under android version 4.4.2 the program passes the netstat command but fails in error the curl command  with the error:

java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [curl, www.google.fr] Working Directory: null Environment: null

I thought I had a permission issue but everything looks fine. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.i("Build ", "version  " + String.valueOf(Build.VERSION.RELEASE));

        String cmd1 = "netstat -an";
        String cmd2 = "curl www.google.fr";
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = null;

        try {
            proc = runtime.exec(cmd1);
            proc = runtime.exec(cmd2);
            proc.getOutputStream().close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

and the manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bernard_zelmans.curl">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

in fact curl is not available as a command in 4.4.1